# iTunes connect : NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key missing but no microphone usage

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I tried to upload my app on iTunes Connect, but the following error appeared :

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

It worked until now. I didn't add new library.

My research conclude on modules which are : 
- Take photo (no videos), but no update from 2 years 
- AVAudioSession library, but no update from 3 years, and doesn't use the `requestRecordPermission`

And I don't use Instabug or iMessage.

I don't need microphone on my app, how I can tell I really don't use it ?
Or how I can find the library which requires the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` key ?

(I don't want to add the key to my info-plist, I think it's not normal to ask the user for something I don't use/want to use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During submission your binary is scanned for the presence of the symbol - `AVAudioSession requestRecordPermission:` in this case.

when found you get an error like the one above.

You can either

- just add the key as there is no prompt for your users until you actually request the permission to use the microphone.
- find which of your framework is containing the symbol (you can search recursively in your build folder framework binaries with tools like `strings` or `nm` or `otool`, grep the above symbol and when found remove the framework from your app).

Comment: Ok, but I don't use the requestRecordPermission. I use the AVAudioSession for a web radio. So the microphone is useless. 
And why now ? Because this module wasn't updated since few years ?

Comment: That's fine. As soon as the symbol is present (irrespectively if used or not) in your app binary or any of your frameworks you need to define the key. As mentioned don't worry about your users being prompted for permissions when not using the mic - we are not on Android.

Comment: Ok thank you, just before to mark your answer as correct, why now and not before ?

Comment: NSMicrophoneUsageDescription is a relatively new check introduced since iOS 10. Since you haven't updated the app for a few years as you said, your previous version was building against previous SDKs?

Comment: I published it one month ago, but the module has 3 years, the SDK version is the same

Comment: Futhermore, I test this module, and the message doesn't pop-up, is it normal ?

Comment: Not familiar with your codebase so can't say how you avoided it before. This check is done server side by Apple during app submission. When they see the symbol anywhere in the binary (or embedded frameworks) without having the Info.plist key defined, they fail with the message above. User is only prompted when you at run time actually call `AVAudioSession requestRecordPermission:` from your code.

Comment: I just had this issue as well (but then for NSLocationUsage description tags). I suppose Apple does not (yet) always check for these tags, or only started doing so since 1 day ago, since yesterday i did an upload which worked fine. Today i fixed 1 more bug and wanted to do a new upload for testflight, but today it was rejected due to this reason. I added the info.plist entries required, and since they aren't called in my code (library related), the users wont know it. Now the build was approved by Apple.